# Did Socrates Help or Hurt Athens by Submitting to Execution?

Tags: ethics, political-philosophy

My question is in the title.  My thoughts are that Crito seems on its face to indicate that Socrates did not want to escape execution because exile would spell *his* ruin, breaking his voluntary social contract with Athens.

Astonishingly, the result of Socrates' execution appears to be that Athens inflicted the *greatest* evil upon itself and Socrates only had to maintain the density required to reflect.

Answer (score 6):

Socrates was a contrarian to the end, and one of his last acts was to force the Athenians to follow through on an execution they never actually wanted or expected to serve.

The goal of Socrates' antagonists was really just to humiliate and discredit him publicly, and in that way to break the fascination he held for the disaffected Athenian youth.  But Socrates wasn't willing to play along and he wasn't scared to die.  In court, he served as his own lawyer.  The Athenian system at that time was that when a conviction had been obtained, the prosecutor and defender would each propose a punishment and the jury would choose the one they found most fitting.  The concept was that this would give the prosecution an incentive to not be too harsh, the defense an incentive to not be too lenient.  However, in this case, the prosecutor went for a grand flamboyant gesture, and asked for death.

The expectation was that Socrates would counter with some minor sentence, maybe some light jail time.  Instead, he proposed that he be sentenced to be fed lavishly at the expense of the state for the rest of his life --a clearly ludicrous "punishment."  To everyone's horror, the only real option left to the jury was either to acknowledge the whole thing as a farce, or to go with death.  Even then, they placed him in a minimum security prison, and gave him every opportunity to escape, which he ignored.

So did this help or hurt Athens?  It certainly did no favors to Athens' reputation or self image.  I imagine, however, Socrates himself would have claimed it had a salubrious effect, by forcing Athens to be more honest with itself and less hypocritical.

Comment: I appreciate your communication, especially the use of *salubrious*!  Only among a bunch of philosophers do you hear such words.  :-) Love it.  I am tempted to accept your answer but fear that would be seen as an abysmal credulity.  lol.  Let's see what others have to say...

Comment: @Ron With me this is a perfect answer, I don't have anything else to say.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I guess my only concern is "Whoever shames another in public is like one who sheds blood." Bava Metzia 58b.  In other words, Socrates would have done better to hire thugs to privately physically beat his accusers (corporal punishment) to the point that they submitted to the truth vs allowing them to leave an indelible scar on Athens.  Or, no?  Athenian populous is looked down upon to this day by everyone in this forum for their allowing such an injustice, no?

Comment: @Ron With appropriate tools you may force to submit anybody to anything, I don't see any positive value in that.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Good point.  I guess what I am desperately trying to figure out is why must blood be shed?  I suppose that irreversible pollution would result from Socrates' followers privately paying his accusers to dialogue privately with Socrates hoping they would come to the revelation that their accusation was unjust.  As you point out, the same pollution occurs if Socrates or anyone acting on his behalf physically beats them.

Comment: I suppose I respectfully cannot accept the above answer because it does not specify whether Athens was helped or hurt by Socrates' submission to execution.  If that fair?

Comment: Submitting to execution was phantastik? [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=GJ2sgpttP7oC&pg=SA11-PA109&lpg=SA11-PA109&dq=phantastics+correct+proportions&source=bl&ots=cKsacsGd_H&sig=PySWWhlYEZKjkc2krX4pFk4WZYA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jyfdVLC0IYqyggSp4IOoBg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=phantastics%20correct%20proportions&f=false)

Comment: @Ron The point of the answer the way I see it is that hurting in one sense may mean healing in other (maybe more essential) sense. In this case reputation or self image is less important than being honest with oneself. And in some especially entangled cases you cannot salvage both - one of them has to go. Dentists have to hurt people quite often.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  Very true but dentistry is a private procedure that benefits the individual.  This seems to be different from a public procedure which aims to benefit the public.  Or, am I off base, off in the weeds?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Respectfully, Athens supposedly was *not* honest with itself thus the irreversible self-inflicted damage because Socrates supposedly *was* honest with himself, in deed, *and* his reputation was extraordinarily increased, at the expense of Athens.  "Know thyself" means to not allow yourself to be swayed by the opinions of the many.  No?  *Self* is physical body, or reputation?  Both, I guess?

Comment: @Ron In this case I think it means sort of "collective self", dominant views, beliefs and standards in evaluating oneself and others in the society interinfluencing its members, such kind of thing. And yes, obviously it is qualitatively more difficult task to rectify collectively interreinforced social aberrations than rectify a deformed jaw, that's why it required life of Socrates rather than professional effort of a dentist

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე So Socrates subscribed to the idea that violence is sometimes required by justice in deed.  In fact, this was what he did - submit to violent action out of defiance of the cries of his own physical self.  It seems to follow that he believed he knew that death of his body is not the ultimate evil or wrong.  However, I thought that Socrates knew that he knew nothing.  Why throw is body under the bus?  Am I even making sense here?...

Comment: @Ron Again, I think the word violence is applicable here no more than in case of dentistry. As for the second part of your comment - well yes he was aware that he knows nothing, but there was also his δαίμων.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  You nailed it.  I too am on to the concept of Socrates' daimon precipitating catharsis.  So, in the end - both Athens *and* Socrates were increased for the good; or, both were decreased for the worse/bad?  What is the answer?  In reality, philosophical inquiry (questions) never delivers answers, right?  We need to vote for fundamental change of this forum - from "Q&A" to "Q2Q".  How did the above answer get scored positive 4 as  there is *no answer* in the provided answer, only suppositions.  Must be argumentum ad populum.  My daimon disallows me from accepting it.  Gadfly.

Comment: @Ron No I think the last paragraph of the answer has it all. Athens lost in terms of reputation and self image but gained (as we all did) in getting a chance to learn what does it mean to really mean what you mean. Socrates lost his life but gained in being able to do what he felt is a right thing to do.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Insofar as humiliating another publicly is tantamount to murder, Socrates was murdered (convicted and killed unjustly) and Athens *killed* itself via ricochet - hard to call it murder when the victim fired the very shot that killed them (humiliated themselves publicly).  The answer seems to include intentional death in the realm of justice.

Comment: Whoever destroys a soul, it is considered as if he destroyed an entire world. And whoever saves a life, it is considered as if he saved an entire world. — Mishnah Sanhedrin 4:9; Babylonian Talmud.  So, had Socrates fled he would have destroyed his soul?  Therefore, it is our duty to die for what we know is true.  Hmmm, this seems like a dangerous position to believe in, especially if the wisest among us know that they know nothing...

Comment: @Ron Is not it actually feasible that placed in the same circumstances everyone of us would feel that the right thing to do would be what he did? Not that everyone would actually do it - that required Socrates...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  Jesus Christ is another that I can think of.  Philosophers in*deed*.